# How to post dynamic generated text-boxes in another aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is generating a dynamic textbox based on the number entered by the user and I want to post it in another aspx page instead of posting it in the same aspx page:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string numOftextbox= TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    int count = int.Parse(numOftextbox.Trim());
    for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
    {
        string id = j.ToString();
        TextBox txtfname = new TextBox();
        txtfname.ID = "TextBox_" + id + "_";
        txtfname.Width = 160;
        txtfname.EnableViewState = true;
        form1.Controls.Add(txtfname);
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a number of TextBoxes, based on some logic, why not just pass the number between the pages, either as a Sesson variable, or in your query string?

Failing that, if you have to pass the TextBoxes for whatever reason, assuming you're loading these new TextBoxes on some subsequent page in a logical sequence, you could just add these TextBoxes to your Session, and access them from there in your later page.

Something like:

```
string numOftextbox= TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    int count = int.Parse(numOftextbox.Trim());
    List<TextBox> txts = new List<TextBox>();
    for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
    {
        string id = j.ToString();
        TextBox txtfname = new TextBox();
        txtfname.ID = "TextBox_" + id + "_";
        txtfname.Width = 160;
        txtfname.EnableViewState = true;
        txts.Add(txtfname);
        form1.Controls.Add(txtfname);
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

    }
    Session["myTextBoxes"] = txts;
```

Then, on your subsequent page:

```
List<TextBox> txts = (List<TextBox>)Session["myTextBoxes"];
//Whatever you want to do with them...
```